# Get "Parse Error" when sending request to YouTube Data API to start a resumable upload session

Tags: swift, alamofire, youtube-data-api

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/using_resumable_upload_protocol

I try to follow this guide to start a resumable session.

But server returns this response :

```swift
success({
    error =     {
        code = 400;
        errors =         (
                        {
                domain = global;
                message = "Parse Error";
                reason = parseError;
            }
        );
        message = "Parse Error";
    };
})
```

Swift 5/ Alamofire 5

```
    let filePath = "/Users/lucas/Documents/test.mp4"
    do{
        let attr = try FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: filePath)
        let dict = attr as NSDictionary
        let fileSize = dict.fileSize()
        let dicSnippest =  ["title": "TestVideo",
                              "description": "_description_",
                              "tags":"gundam",
                              "catagoryId":"22"]
        let dicStatus = ["privacyStatus": "private",
                         "embedded": "True",
                         "license": "youtube"]
        let sessionParam = ["snippet": dicSnippest,
                            "status": dicStatus
                            ]
        let targetUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?uploadType=resumable&part=snippet,status"
        let sessionHeaders = HTTPHeaders([
            "Authorization": "Bearer \(token)",
            "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            "Content-Length": "\(fileSize)",
            "X-Upload-Content-Length": "\(fileSize)",
            "X-Upload-Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"])

        print("token: \(token)")

        print("\(filePath): \(fileSize) bytes")
        AF.request(targetUrl, method: .post, parameters: sessionParam, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: sessionHeaders).responseJSON {
                response in
                print("Http Status Code: \(String(describing: response.response?.statusCode))")
                switch (response.result)
                {
                case .success(_):
                    print("Get Server Response!!")
                    print(response.result)
                    break
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Failure!!")
                    print(error)
                    break
                }
            }
    } catch {
    }
```

BTW, I modify the parameter of `AF.request` - `encoding` from `URLEncoding.httpBody` to `JSONEncoding.default`.

This error is happened:

```
responseSerializationFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.inputDataNilOrZeroLength)
```

Comment: s/catagoryId/categoryId/

Comment: Still get the same result after fixing typo